# Random integer in Java

Tags: java

This is the question that i got. 
Enter 2 integer (x and y) and print random integer between x and y. 
I want to know why my code does not print the random integer.
I am still a beginner in java, any help would be nice. Thank you.

```
import java.util.*;
class Random_integer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random randomNum = new Random();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int integer1, integer2;
        System.out.print("Enter two integer : \n ");
        System.out.print("\n Integer 1 : ");
        integer1 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("\n Integer 2 :");
        integer2 = input.nextInt();
        randomNum = new Random(integer1, integer2);
        System.out.print("\n Random number : " +randomNum);
    }
}
```

Comment: `randomNum` is a `Random` object (a random number generator). You need to call a *method* on your `Random` object to generate an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below. The parameters in `randomize(int x, int y)` where `x` is minimum number
and `y` is maximum number.

```
import java.util.*;

class Random_integer
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int integer1, integer2;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.print("Enter two integer : \n ");
        System.out.print("\n Integer 1 : ");
        integer1 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("\n Integer 2 :");
        integer2 = input.nextInt();

        Random_integer ri = new Random_integer();
        ri.randomize(integer1,integer2);
    }

    public void randomize (int x,int y) {
        Random randomNum = new Random();
        int rand = randomNum.nextInt((y-x)+1)+x;
        System.out.print("\n Random number : " +rand);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`java.util.Random` is a class used to generate random numbers. The constructor doesn't take the minimum and maximum value as arguments, but the `nextInt()` method does what you want:

```
randomNum = new Random();
System.out.println("Random number: " + random.nextInt(integer1, integer2));
```

Comment: `Random(long seed)` is used extensively for repeatable testing and the like.

Comment: @chrylis Where do I use `Random(long seed)`?

Comment: It's inaccurate to say that "the constructor doesn't take arguments". There's a default constructor, sure, but there's also a commonly-used one that does.

Comment: @chrylis Okay, I changed it

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the `Random` constructor incorrectly, `Random(integer1, integer2)` will not compile because `Random` does not have a constructor that takes two integer arguments.

If you want to create a random number in a range, use this:

```
int rand = randomNum.nextInt((integer2 - integer1) + 1) + integer1
```

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.Random` is a random number generator, not a number. You can **use it** to generate a random integer like so:

```
Randrom rand = new Random();
int randomNum = x + rand.nextInt(y - x + 1);
```